# Como faço para ter tempo de expiração no link de recuperação?

Tags: codeigniter

Eu fiz uma função no pelo *codeigniter* para recuperação de senha e está tudo funcionando, só que eu queria que expirasse o link tem um x tempo/dia.

Qual a lógica usar nessa situação?

Comment: Manda no link  uma query-string que é uma data criptografada que é a data limite. O codeigniter tem função de criptografia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma boa solução seria, ao solicitar recuperação de senha:

Tendo uma constante que define o tempo de expiração;

1. Criar um token com a informação da data atual;
2. Associar esse token ao usuário no banco de dados;
3. Enviar o link de recuperação com o token na url;

Quando o link for acessado:

1. Recuperar o Token via `GET`;
2. Verificar se o token é igual ao banco de dados;
3. Extrair a data do token e comparar com a atual, levando em consideração o prazo de expiração que foi definido na constante.

Se houver alteração de senha, altere ou remova o token para invalidar o link.

Essa é uma maneira genérica e segura de se fazer, claro! Não sendo a única.

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Comment: Mais e se eu quisesse que o tempo de expiração fosse por exemplo em 2 horas, como eu faria?, estou sem ideias aqui no momento pois tmb nunca pensei em fazer isso.

Comment: Inclua a data e hora no token e compare se a diferença da data/hora atual com a data/hora do token é menor que 2. Caso, seja. tudo ok! Caso não, informe que o link está expirado.